# Golang net.Listen IPv6

Tags: go, ipv6

I'm attempting to get IPv6 working with Golang net.Listen() however I keep getting the following error:

> listen tcp [xxxx::xxx:xxxx:fe4f:7e0b]:9443: bind: invalid argument

Code:

```
s.Listener, err = net.Listen("tcp", config.LocalNode().IP+":"+config.LocalNode().Port)
```

Any ideas why I'm running into this problem? IPv4 seems to work np

Comment: You've x'ed out the IP address prefix so I can't tell, but are you sure that's a routable ipv6 address? Did you try using the `tcp6` network specifically?

Comment: @JimB I've intentionally "x" the IPv6 address out. I've doubled check to make sure the IPv6 address I'm using is valid. Also, I did trying using tcp6 specifically unfortunately I still have the same issue.

Comment: I know you x'ed it out intentionally, but it's obfuscating the type of address it is. Guessing by the pattern of x's, you may be binding a non-routable address without a proper scope, which will give you this error. Is this really a valid, globally scoped address?

Comment: @JimB Sorry, you are right I was using a non-routable IPv6 address. It now works. Perhaps the error should be a little more descriptive. I appreciate your support and time.

Comment: See https://github.com/golang/go/issues/53106

Comment: See https://pkg.go.dev/net/netip#Addr.IsGlobalUnicast

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Attempting to bind a link-scoped ipv6 address without a proper scope will result in this error from the operating system. If you actually want a link-scoped address, you have to provide the proper scope id, e.g.

```
"[fe80::4c3:3cff:fe4f:7e0b%eth0]:9443"
```

Otherwise you need to use a valid globally scoped ipv6 address.

```
"[2600:1f18:63ef:e802:355f:aede:dbba:2c03]:9443"
```